# Add a one unique div for three different images on three different pages?

Tags: html, css, image

Beginner here!

I am struggling with a task.
It is requested to add one div ID with a unique name "div=heroimage" to all three different images on three different pages. However, they are in the same location on each page.

CSS
Home, second page and third

#resort

```
    { 
                 height: 200px;
                 background-image: url(resort.jpg);
                 background-size: 100% 100%;
                 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
                

    }
```

#hotel

```
    {            

                 height: 200px;
                 background-image: url(hotel.jpg);
                 background-size: 100% 100%;
                 background-repeat: no-repeat; 


    }
```

#casa

```
    {           
                 height: 200px;
                 background-image: url(casa.jpg);
                 background-size: 100% 100%;
                 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
                 
    }
```

---

The other two are identical just with the ID name different and title.
If I change all the three with "div=heroimage"  what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

You can take the below idea and extend it to strictly `id`s.

```css
#resort,
#hotel,
#casa {
  --backgroundImageUrl: url(resort.jpg);
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: var(--backgroundImageUrl);
}

#hotel {
  --backgroundImageUrl: url(hotel.jpg);
}

#casa {
  --backgroundImageUrl: url(casa.jpg);
}
```

---

You're allowed to add multiple classes as a value of a `class` attribute.

This:

```css
.heroImage.option1 { … }
```

Matches:

```html
<div class="heroImage option1"></div>
```

I would create a shared `class` and then unique classes for each version. The unique classes override a [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), which adjusts the background image as necessary.

```css
.heroImage {
  --backgroundImageUrl: url(resort.jpg);
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: var(--backgroundImageUrl);
}

.heroImage.hotel {
  --backgroundImageUrl: url(hotel.jpg);
}

.heroImage.casa {
  --backgroundImageUrl: url(casa.jpg);
}
```

**Resorts page** (default—doesn't need the override `class`)

```html
<div class="heroImage"></div>
```

**Hotel page**

```html
<div class="heroImage hotel"></div>
```

**Casa page**

```html
<div class="heroImage casa"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it requires an ID not a class.

Comment: @Soso I've updated my answer for you using strictly `id`s.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class that has all the identical pieces in a `. class` .. Then the specific image, via unique `# id`s:

```
.heroimage{ 
    height: 200px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

#resort{
    background-image: url(resort.jpg);
}
#hotel{
    background-image: url(hotel.jpg);
}
#casa{
    background-image: url(casa.jpg);
}
```

The resulting `divs` would look like:

```
<div id="resort" class="heroimage">
<div id="hotel" class="heroimage">
<div id="casa" class="heroimage">
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score -1):

They could be testing your understanding of CCS variables, stuff like:

```
background-color: var(--white);
```

Or it could be about inheritance

```
p { color: green; }
```